# IIS7 won't server Flash swf file that uses XML data

Tags: iis, google-chrome, flash

I have an SWF file that I am attempting to serve up using SWFObjects 2.2.  It works everywhere except when served up from my server to a Chrome browser.  Specifically:

- local IIS 7, Chrome, IE, and FF all work
- server browsing through local file system works on Chrome, IE, and FF
- server browsing IIS 7, works in IE and FF, not Chrome

My server IIS will serve up normal SWF files to a Chrome browser, just not this specific SWF file that uses an XML data file.  My SWF file, XML data file, and referenced images are all in the same folder (wanted to eliminate that as a possible source of the error early on).

What possible IIS 7 setting would prevent a Chrome browser from rendering an SWF file that uses an XML data file?  Is there any way to troubleshoot in the Chrome browser to get some kind of idea of what the error is?

Here is the .htm file (generated by SWFObjects) that I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.registerObject("myFlashContent", "9.0.0");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="600" id="myFlashContent">
                <param name="movie" value="banner.swf" />
                <param name="flashvars" value="file=data.xml" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="banner.swf" width="800" height="600">
                    <param name="flashvars" value="file=data.xml" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using this on my server with Chrome, all I get is a blank white page.

TIA,

Mike

Comment: Try taking out the if IE stuff.  The browsers should know how to ignore information that doesn't apply to them.  Also, you might need to have embed tags as well.

Comment: Can you request the XML file directly in Chrome? Try it while the inspectors are running, the info should be handy in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

> Using this on my server with Chrome, all I get is a blank white page.

If you right click the place where the swf is supposed to be, do you see a 'Swf not loaded' message in the context menu? If so, bring up Chrome's Developer console, launch Network tab and refresh the page. you should see a request to the server there for the swf and that might give you hints on why the load didn't succeed.

If you don't see a 'SWF' not loaded' message, and see a regular Chrome context menu, the browser didn't even attempt loading.

Comment: Arul - When I right click where the Flash file should be I get a Flash context menu.  Also, when I use the Network tab in Chrome it shows me that it did download the SWF file, it just isn't showing it.  I'm pretty sure Chrome is having some type of problem displaying the xml data for the Flash movie, but I don't know what it could be because it works in every other browser!  :(